# Custom command-spawned banners

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been spawning banners on the wall using the `/fill` command, and it works. The only problem is that I want the banners to be solid white, whereas right now they are all black.

Comment: Use the Tag `{Base:15,Patterns:[]}}`

Answer (score 1):

Use `/fill`'s NBT parameter to set the `Base` tag to `15` (white):

```
/fill X1 Y1 Z1 X2 Y2 Z2 standing_banner 0 replace {Base:15}
```

The numeric values that you can use in `Base` or `Patterns` for a banner are:

```
╔═══════╦════════════╗
║ Value ║   Color    ║
╠═══════╬════════════╣
║    15 ║ White      ║
║    14 ║ Orange     ║
║    13 ║ Magenta    ║
║    12 ║ Light Blue ║
║    11 ║ Yellow     ║
║    10 ║ Lime       ║
║     9 ║ Pink       ║
║     8 ║ Gray       ║
║     7 ║ Light Gray ║
║     6 ║ Cyan       ║
║     5 ║ Purple     ║
║     4 ║ Blue       ║
║     3 ║ Brown      ║
║     2 ║ Green      ║
║     1 ║ Red        ║
║     0 ║ Black      ║
╚═══════╩════════════╝
```